# ReplyingKafkaTemplate timeout in Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have very regularly experienced timeouts using ReplyingKafkaTemplate and request/reply pattern for synchronous calls.  It has been suggested this is due to consumers and that appears to be correct because what resolves renaming the consumer group on the calling side of request/reply and redeploying the service. This is not an optimal solution however, and I would like to prevent this error from occurring. To recap I from Service A to Service B I make a synchronous request and after a while due to staleness or something eventually I see a timeout in this request.  The solution I have found is to change name of consumer group in service A and redeploy but I need a better resolution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't think of anything in the framework that would cause such a problem; have you tried enabling DEBUG logging?

Comment: When i ask you about it before you said it might be related to consumer groups

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to; there are issues when there are multiple client instances with incorrect configuration, but I can't think of anything that would cause it to stop working after some period of running fine.

Comment: Ok, well I will try and confirm the exact behavior again.

Comment: there are a lot deployments. All i can say is its not topic names

Comment: they have not changed at all

Comment: I can't think of anything that would cause this behavior; if you can create a small, simple, complete example that exhibits it, I can take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161248/o-s-k-r-replyingkafkatemplate-reply-timed-out-for-producerrecord

Comment: I really doubt its just me. I have a team of 4 people on my project and we really are all seeing this.  Are there settings that effect when a client tries to reestablish connection to broker to listen?

Comment: I am wondering really if there should not be something in the logs on the receiving side indicating if its listening or stopped listening on the request topic?

Comment: I suggest you enable debug logging on the server side to figure out what's going on.